# How to exclude _id and _cls from a .only query?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

My `message` collection looks like:

```
[{
'_id': 'f63d2474-bb1c-42dc-ac41-9248bdda82a4',
'_cls': 'Message',
'_date_created': {'$date': 1646213357523},
'_date_modified': {'$date': 1646213357814},
'message': 'hello',
'name': 'tom'
}]
```

I want to only return the 'name' and 'message'. When I try

```
Message.objects.only("name", "message").to_json()
```

It still returns `_id` and `_cls`

```
[{
'_id': 'f63d2474-bb1c-42dc-ac41-9248bdda82a4',
'_cls': 'Message',
'message': 'hello',
'name': 'tom'
}]
```

How can I exclude the `_id` and `_cls` from the result?

For reference, both `_id` and `_cls` are indexes

Answer (score 0):

the `_id` field is returned by default with mongoengine, I guess it's the same for all the variables that start with an `_`.

you can use `exclude()` to remove the fields you don't want. `exclude()` and `ònly()`methods can be chained

the `_id` field in mongo is resolved to `id` in MongoEngine
so you have to do

```
Message.objects.only("name", "message").exclude("id", "cls").to_json()
```

---

There is also a `fields()` method with is the method used by both `only()` and `exclude()`

```
Message.objects.field(name=1, message=1, id=0, cls=0).to_json()
```

Comment: I tried the `.only().exclude()` pattern but it didnt fix my issue, I'll try the `.field()` method and let you know if it works